# Remove two hyphens from MimeBodyPart javax.mail.message

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, mime, smime

I create a s/mime using javax.mail 1.5.5

Unsigned mime message as follows:

[image: unsigned mime message]

As you see there is a two hyphens at the end of part

I create s/mime then two hyphens are removed so signed value is different

[image: signed mime message]

```
public class TestKepSignStackOf {

private static final String UNSIGNED_MIME = "E:/sign/b/unsigned.eml";
private static final String SIGNED_VALUE = "E:/sign/b/smime.p7s";
private static final String SIGNED_MIME = "E:/sign/b/signed.eml";

public static void main(String[] a) {

    // create some properties and get the default Session
    Properties props = new Properties();
    // props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    // session.setDebug(debug);

    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session, null);
    try {

        // create a message
        msg.addHeader("X-TR-REM-iletiTip", "standart");
        msg.addHeader("X-TR-REM-iletiID", "");
        msg.addHeader("X-TR-REM-iletiDetay", "detay");


        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mail@mail.com.tr"));
        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(
            "mail-test@mail.com.tr")};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
        msg.setSubject("Test 4");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        MultipartSigned multipartSigned = new MultipartSigned();


        MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        bodyPart.setText("<b>Hello World</b>", "utf-8", "html");

        Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart();
        multiPart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);


        MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
        body.setContent(multiPart);

        multipartSigned.addBodyPart(body);
        msg.setContent(multipartSigned);
        try (OutputStream str = Files.newOutputStream(Paths
                .get(UNSIGNED_MIME))) {
            msg.writeTo(str);
        };
        signMimeMessage();

        MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        attachPart.attachFile(SIGNED_VALUE,
                "application/pkcs7-signature; name=smime.p7s", "base64");
        attachPart.setFileName("smime.p7s");
        attachPart.addHeader("Content-Description",
                "S/MIME Cryptographic Signature");

        multipartSigned.addBodyPart(attachPart);

        msg.saveChanges();

        try (OutputStream str = Files.newOutputStream(Paths
                .get(SIGNED_MIME))) {
            msg.writeTo(str);
            str.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error = " + ex.getMessage());

    }

}
```

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your unsigned example is wrong.  It's already a multipart/signed message, but an unsigned message would just contain the interior multipart/mixed content.  The signing should be over the entire multipart/mixed content, not the header and boundary used to embed that multipart/mixed content in the multipart/signed part.

Comment: Dear Bill, Thank you for your concern. but why this is so hard?

Comment: Regarding to above code I have to sign below content, right?
------=_Part_1_32879825.1458340006441

<b>Hello World</b>
------=_Part_1_32879825.1458340006441--

Comment: Yes, I believe that's correct, but you really need to read the RFC to figure it out for sure.

Comment: I solved the issue, wrapper multipart should be written as unsigned w/o header Thank you Bill

Answer (score 0):

Problem was related signing process. So before creating unsigned file (body to be signed) whole message should be saved using message.saveChanges() method.
Updated code was on below

```
        MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
        body.setContent(multiPart);

        multipartSigned.addBodyPart(body);
        msg.setContent(multipartSigned);
        msg.saveChanges();
        try (OutputStream str = Files.newOutputStream(Paths
                .get(UNSIGNED_MIME))) {
            body.writeTo(str);
            str.close();
        };
```